# How can i access react-native component from out of component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to access a Text Input of a React-native component from a function which in out of the component. I want to clear TextInput through refs in *clearForm()* function.

MyComponent.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class myComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          ref= {'email'}
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Actions.js

```js
function clearForm(data){
  for(var input_name in data){
    /////???
    //this.refs[input_name].setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for taking so long, but this should work:

```
// myComponent.js
class myComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { 
      emailText: ''
    }
  }

   clearField() { 
    this.setState({ 
      emailText: ''
    })
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          ref= {'email'}
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Email"
          value={this.state.emailText}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Actions.js
function clearForm(data){
  for(var input_name in data){
    this.refs[input_name].clearField();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the ref attribute to a function.  Check out the documentation here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html

```
ref={ input => this.myInput = input }
```

There is actually an example of this specifically in that doc: https://snack.expo.io/?session_id=snack-session-HylUL01kbf

Answer (score 0):

Try using the component ref name as a prop, like this:

```
this.refs.email.setNativeProps({text: ''});
```

Comment: I've tried . error is not in input_name. the function is in another file. How to access the component elements.